# Eclipse showing wrong workspace directory in classpath after selection "run as java application" causing "class not found"

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, maven, classpath

I have a Java Spring Boot/Maven application which I checked out into a workspace "C:\PA4Workspaces" from Subversion.

This was one of many projects which I checked out, including one with the name "ILCore".

Originally, the project in question defaulted to the name "ILCore (3)". I renamed "ILCore (3)" to something different, call it "MyAppServices".

MyAppServices has two sub-projects, one of which is named "Core".

I want to run the Spring Boot application in "Core". When I right-click and select "run as java application", it properly displays the class that launches the Spring Boot application at the top of the list of classes.

However, when I run it, it gets the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class 
        (1)\target\classes;C:\Users\xxxxx.m2\repository\com\mycompnay\bip\rest-server\1.5.0.0-SNAPSHOT\rest-server-1.5.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar; 
.
.  
<many jar files from the repository>;
. 
.
C:\PA4Workspaces\ILCore
```

It looks like the default path is "C:\PA4Workspaces\ILCore" instead of "C:\PA4Workspaces\MyAppServices\Core"

Is this the problem? If so, how do I fix it? Note the name in the .project file is correct. The name of the project in the part .project file is also correct, although I had to manually change it from the original name.

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Right click on project,select maven -> update project as shown below from below context menu image.

[image: Context menu]

Step2: Then make sure the **Force update of screenshots/release** checkbox should be ticked as shown in below image

[image: Checkbox selection]

Step3: click Ok and now try to re-run the application and it could probably solve your error.

Comment: Unfortunately, it gives the same error (:

Comment: I notice there is no "classes" folder in the target directory. Do you think that might be a problem?

Comment: Execute maven goal - clean install and build successfully hence all the respective class files will be generated in the target directory and then try to perform the above update project steps.

Comment: I've been doing that. Ultimately I created another workspace and did a fresh checkout under the same name I should have checked it out in the first place, and now it's working. Something about the rename fouled it up.